# How to when I came to the end of my web page my popup open up side

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, tomahawk

i use tomahawk. I want to show a table in the popup window. Because my link locate under my web page can not be displayed all of this pop-up.

How do I open this window up?

Comment: its not clear what do you want to do. some more detail and code may help.

Comment: popup displayed when link onmouseover. link is located bottom of the page. when the popup displayed it extends the page length, so user must scroll the page to see the popup content. I want to locate popup bottom according to link position. in other words, I want to open popup upside of the link so user do not scroll the page.